# Drupal Flag module and fetching uid

Tags: drupal, view, flags

I'm afraid I already know the answer, but I was wondering if someone could confirm this for me.

I've set up a flag on a content type.  When that piece of content is flagged once, I want it removed from the main list so that it can't be flagged again (at least, not easily from the main list).  I set this flag up as a "Global" flag so that when anyone flags it, it's flagged, period.

Now I'd like to set up a view that lists who flagged what, but am running into a problem where the UID that's returned is 0 for each piece of content.  I check the database and the uid column inside the flag_content table lists 0 for every flag.  Is this because I set the flag as "global", and thus the flag module doesn't record the uid of the flagging user?  Shouldn't they warn you if that's the case?

Thanks very much.

Comment: So, in case anyone is wondering, the answer is YES. http://drupal.org/node/339657

Answer (score 1):

It is true, because the flag is set to "global" the uid will always be 0.  But there is a [workaround](http://drupal.org/node/339657#comment-2639686).

**Workaround:**

> 1. You need to have the modules CCK and Rules installed.
> 2. Create a usereference field in the content type/s you want to be flagged
>      by your global flag and you set it to
>      invisible (if you have permissions by
>      field remember to give view rights to
>      whatever users you need).
> 3. Create a rule for the event "a node has been flagged", and you set the
>      global flag you want as reference.
> 4. Create an action "populate a field", you select te usereference
>      field you have created before and in
>      "Advanced: Specify the fields value
>      with PHP code" you put:
>      `return array(0 => array('uid' => $flagging_user->uid));`
>      This will put the uid of the flagging user in your
>      usereference field.
> 5. In your view now you just need to display the usereference field and you
>      will see for each node who has flagged
>      it.

It is pretty simple to implement and use with Views.  You will need the [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) modules installed for this to work.